# Xamarin command binding to 2 argument methods

Tags: c#, xamarin, delegates, commandbinding

I am newbie and I am not familiar enough with delegates and lambda statements. So it might too simple but here is my issue:

I am trying to implement async subscription method with 2 argument by using command binding in Xamarin. When I wrote the command initializing shown below, code editor says

> Action does not take two arguments

So what should I do to utilize two argument async methods for command binding?

```
//Command initializing line cause an error which says " Action<object> does not take two arguments. 
Subscribe = new Command(async (productId,payload) => await SubscribeAsync(productId,payload));
....
public async Task<bool> SubscribeAsync(string productId, string payload)
{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish it, passing an object which contain all necessary parameters. Actually, @Junior Jiang suggested that. But I was also looking to code it in one-line lambda notation.

Here is my solution.

```
        public SubscriptionViewModel()
        {
        subscriptionInfo = new SubscriptionInfo("s01", "payload");

        Subscribe = new Command<SubscriptionInfo>(async (s) => await GetSubscritionsOptsAsync(this.subscriptionInfo));
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Great! Remember to mark the answer when you can. If using object as parameter, you could custom a class to deal with input parameters. Then outside can use one-line to init the object and use to pass.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a model object as paramater, and it could contain more than one argument.

For example:

```
ICommand SubscribeCommand = new Command((parmaters) => {
    var item = (parmaters as CheckItem);
    var one = item.productId;
    var two = item.payload;
});
```

**CheckItem.cs**:

```
public class CheckItem 
{

    public string productId { set; get; }

    public string payload { set; get; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Command` definition [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.command?view=xamarin-forms)

> Command(Action)   Initializes a new instance of the Command class.

The `Action` class [does not take any input arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0):

```
public delegate void Action();
```

So you can only instantiate it with a method that takes no parameters and returns nothing

Comment: agree. But I need two argument to  pass into method. There should be a way.